# Configure IDEA to deploy using ivy

Tags: intellij-idea, ivy

I have a project that uses IVY. My build script resolves the dependencies well.

I have a library (lets call it `Project_libs`) configured in IntelliJ iml file so that when I deploy the application the jars get published to the server.

I have an ant task `ide-setup` which copies the necessary jars from Ivy local repo to `Project_libs` so these jars are available to IDEA during deployement.

Lets say I make changes to a common library like utils.

- Build the common library.
- Go to the projects that declared this common library as a dependency and run `ide-setup`
- Then start the server.

Is there a direct way in which I can configure IDEA to read the dependencies from the ivy.xml file instead of doing this convoluted process of setting up the whole thing.

Comment: You can try [a third-party IvyIDEA plug-in](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=3612).

Comment: You charge how much for this tool ? I am glad I am not  the one paying!

Comment: Ivy support is not advertised, if third-party solutions do not work, you can't blame JetBrains for this. Follow [this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6346) to know when/if it will be added in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about InelliJ IDEA, but I believe you could accomplish what you want using ant and IVY.  From the [IVY documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html)

```
<ivy:buildlist reference="build-path" ivyfilepath="ivy/ivy.xml" leaf="mymodule">
  <fileset dir="projects" includes="**/build.xml"/>
</ivy:buildlist>

Builds a list of build.xml files sorted according to the ivy.xml files found in an
ivy directory relative to those build files. Only build.xml files of modules which
have dependencies (direct or transitive) on mymodule are put in the result list.
```

So if you set leaf equal to utils, it could return you a list of build.xml files that depend on utils in dependency order.  Then all you would have to do is go through those build.xml files in order and invode their build process (probably through a subant call)